# Eliminating cyclic dependency

Tags: c#, design, dependency-injection, class-design, dependency-management

I want to avoid cyclic dependency in this schema:

[image: Diagram]

`DbRepository` needs `IUserDbEntityFactory` to create `User` entity which needs `IUserPublishedInfoInitializer` to create `UserPublishedInfo` on request. And `UserPublishedInfoInitializer` itself needs `IDbRepository` to check whether the user is currently present in cache and active to set `IsOnline` property on `UserPublishedInfo`.

Both `CreateUser` and `TryGetCachedUser` methods use the same internal things like caching and locks inside `DbRepository`.

`User` is a an aggregation root db entity without interface.

`DbRepository` requires `IUserDbEntityFactory` which requires `IUserPublishedInfoInitializer` to construct `User` and makes cyclic dependency back to `DbRepository`. I usually use constructor dependency injection but in this case it won't work because of cyclic dependency so this is what the question is about.

Also I don't want to move `MakePublishedInfo` out of `User` because it's actually an implicit conversation in C# and is used very frequently in the code.

And passing `IDbRepository` to `IUserPublishedInfoInitializer.Init` as an argument is neither what I want because why should this implementation depend on what's using it? This breaks encapsulation.

On the schema only `User` and `UserPublishedInfo` are dynamically created objects (others are created at startup).

Should I change this design and what it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the Dependency of IUserPublishedInfoInitializer on IDbRepository. Instead inject this as a construction parameter into the concrete UserPublishedInfoInitializer.

your dependency graph then looks like

```
IUserPublishedInfoInitializer
    IUserDbEntityFactory 
    User
        IDbRepository
            DbRepository
            UserPublishedInfoInitializer
```

edit --

OK you just need a special constructor on DbRepository or child class

```
public DbRepository()
{
    var upii = new UserPublishedInfoInitializer(this);
    var this.userDbEntityFactory = new UserDbEntityFactory(upii);
}
```

if you still want to it via DI you could have a DbRepositoryFactory to do the same thing

```
public class DbRepositoryFactory : IDbRepositoryFactory 
{
    pulbic DbRepository Repo {get;set;}
}

public UserPublishedInfoInitializer(IDbRepositoryFactory repo)
{
    var this.DbRepositoryFactory= repo.Repo; //dont use this yet!!!
}

public Main()
{
    var dbfac = new DbRepositoryFactory()
    var upii = new UserPublishedInfoInitializer(dbfac);
    var repo = new DbRepository(upii)
    dbfac.Repo = repo;
}
```

However, I'm not sure injecting MORE things really helps with your core problem which is having the User object being uncreateable without a repository.

hard to say without seeing the whole problem but, just from the naming it seems like UserPublishedInfoInitializer is unnecessary, your repository could take responsibility for creating the UserPublishedInfo object if User is effectivly the aggregate root and always has a UserPublishedInfo property

Comment: On my graph all the dependencies are specified on concrete classes. I mean that the concrete implementation of `IUserPublishedInfoInitializer` depends on `IDbRepository` but the interface itself doesn't. And everything is already injected with a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The ubiquitous solution to the circular dependency problem is to introduce the observer pattern. One implementation is to use Domain Events.

If you think this is too much try to inject the `IDbRepository` dependency into the `UserPublishedInfoInitializer` class via property injection. With pure DI you would have something like

```
var upi = new UserPublishedInfoInitializer();
var fac = new UserDbEntityFactory(upi);
var repo = new DbRepository(fac);
upi.DbRepository = repo;
```

However this is the last recommended solution.

I think you can break the circular dependency if you remove the `TryGetCachedUser` method into its interface (`IUserCache`). `DbRepository` makes sure the user is inserted in the cache and `UserPublishedInfoInitializer` can inspect if an user is in the cache.

Comment: 1. On property injection: why should `UserPublishedInfoInitializer` class know anything about overall design (how it's going to be used)? It needs some things so it's expected to just require them in the constructor otherwise it knows too much!

Comment: 2. `CreateUser` and `TryGetCachedUser` use the same internal locks and indexing so they are hard to split.

Comment: The constructor injection is more expressive than the the property injection but both achieve the same goal: to inject a dependency. Either you use constructor injection or property injection, the UserPublishedInfoInitializer would still know about IDbRepository. With property injection you break the constructors chain at UserPublishedInfoInitializer.